# Setting keyboard layout options when keyboard connects

Tags: keyboard-layout

On xubuntu 20.04 (using the xfce environment), I use `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps` to map my capslock key to ctrl. This works fine, but unfortunately whenever I use my KVM to switch computers, the keyboard layout gets reset when it reconnects. Is there some way to set keyboard layout options whenever a keyboard connects?

Comment: Please edit your question and let us know which Ubuntu version you are on, if it's a desktop or server, and - if it's a desktop - which desktop environment.

Comment: Since asking this question I ended up switching to kde-plasma which has direct configuration of ctrl/capslock behavior in its control panel. However it'd still be nice to know how to make this work reliably in xfce.

Comment: Doesn't XFCE have a similar GUI for keybord configuration? At least I think it has, but I have no Xubuntu installation available atm to check it out.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I thought there was but I can't find it.